# exit status problem when compiling program

Tags: c

Everytime i compile my program, it appears this error: 1d returned 1 exit status. And my code doesn't even have a exit status.
i put #include "oraculo.h" because i created it and activate_oracle() is from there.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "oraculo.h"

void limpaBuff()
{ // limpa se o valor for invalido
    int n;
    while((n=getchar())!=EOF && n!='\n');
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int tamanho=-1, cor=-1, repeticao=-1;
    do
    {
        printf("Tamanho d   a chave secreta[4 a 8]:");
        scanf("%d", &tamanho);
        printf("Numero de cores[6 a 12]:");
        scanf("%d", &cor);
        printf("Coloque 1 para repeticao e 0 para nao repeticao:");
        scanf("%d", &repeticao);
        limpaBuff();
    }
    while(tamanho<4 || tamanho>8 || cor<6 || cor>12 || (repeticao!=0 && repeticao!=1));
    activate_oracle(tamanho, cor, repeticao);

}
```

Comment: Look at the **full** output and you'll see you have an "undefined reference" error as shown in the duplicate.

Comment: i got undefined reference now, but i included my oraculo.h. why is that? i also put oraculo.h and oraculo.o in the same place as my project

Comment: you need to link the resulting object files together. When you have both `main.o` and `oraculo.o` you need to link them aginst each other. you can do this by calling `gcc` only with the object files: `gcc main.o oraculo.o -o out`

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to call gcc on windows terminal? Or do i have to get the virtual box and move to Linux so i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add `return 0;` to the end of your `main()` function because that's where exit codes should be put. Also, if your code does happen to error it will return with an exit code of 1.

Comment: i still get the error after adding that

Comment: Are you sure that your code doesn't actually have an error?

Comment: the only error i get is the 1d returned 1 exit status and no warnings either